# How do handle this in a web app?

Tags: web-services, web, security

I have a database-backed web app. I need this functionality:

There's a table with rows and I need to generate a URL. If a user clicks on the URL (say included in an e-mail), a column value will be updated for the specific id.

I know I could create a link, say http://server.com/update?id=30303030&newvalue='dxckdk';

However, this won't be very secure as someone could try sending requests with generated ids.

What would be the best way to secure this?

Thank you for all your help!

J

Comment: You need server-side access control.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this, please? Thank you!

Comment: Your server needs to check whether the logged-in user isallowed to do this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control

Answer (score 0):

You can try using encryption on querystring values. this way no one can alter data infact no one can get what you are sending in querystring. This trick has downside of overhead of encryption/decryption but it is secure.

I like this method as it is chain-able and support both encrypted and normal query strings
http://weblogs.asp.net/bradvincent/archive/2008/10/27/helper-class-querystring-builder-chainable.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25719/Query-string-encryption-for-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

Use [randomly generated UUIDs (tokens)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID)

1. Would almost guarantee that there will be no predictable sequence
2. Cannot be replayed, i.e. the tokens are for one-time use only. Once http://server.com/update?token=mxyzptlk has been requested, that key value should not be reusable
3. that cannot be reverse engineered by any means. Unlike encrypted values that can be compromised once their source material or encryption key are compromised. UUIDs are not predictable. AFAIK, they're also not susceptible to reverse engineering.
4. They're relatively trivial to generate and with low processing overhead (depending on your platform anyways)